# ComboBox Value in MS Access SQL Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a comboBox on a form named stockDetailsForm, that selects the stock details from a table. I want to use the selected value as part of my SQL query in Access. However, this does not generate a result.

How do I use the selected item in the comboBox (named CBStock)?

```
SELECT Stock.Symbol, Stock.StockDescription, Stock.AvailableUnits, StockType.TypeDescription, Category.CategoryDescription, CurrencyID.Currency
FROM Stock, StockType, Category, CurrencyID
WHERE (StockType.TypeDescription = [Forms]![stockDetailsForm]![CBStock]) AND (((Stock.TypeID)=[StockType].[TypeID]) AND ((Stock.BusinessCategoryID)=[Category].[CategoryID]) AND ((Stock.CurrencyID)=[CurrencyID].[CurrencyID]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your combobox is bound to *TypeID*, not *TypeDescription*, thus:

```
StockType.TypeID = [Forms]![stockDetailsForm]![CBStock])
```